# Should the args of subprocess.run() be expanded or not?

Tags: python-3.x, subprocess

With python 3.7.1, both centos7 and chromeos, the following code errors out

```
from subprocess import run
run('git diff --quiet @{u} @{0}'.split(), shell=True)
```

but

```
run('git diff --quiet @{u} @{0}', shell=True)
```

works.

There are other occasions where split and not-split both works. When do they differ? Is one be more preferable than the other?

Comment: Which OS are you using?

Comment: Generally speaking, you use a list of parameters for `shell=False` (in which case a single string would have to be split into parameters anyway), and a single string for `shell=True` (in which case a list of parameters would have to be joined to pass to the shell).